# Python: Existing environment variables which need to be added again to execute

Tags: python, windows, environment-variables

I'm trying to execute a command which runs a program that uses perl and python. Although both of them are already in PATH, I get this error `'perl' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.
'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.`  So I tried `os.putenv('PATH', dir)` but only one was taken in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So try

```
os.putenv('PATH', dir + ";" + otherdir)
```

Comment: Thanks but why couldn't Python recognise the programs even though they were already in the environment variables?

Comment: Apparently they were not... I'd suggest to put some debugging statements like "print os.environ" in your code to see what's going on.